# Could not create type for webservice.asmx

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, asmx

I have a web service and it uses some other projects dll files. Everything is ok when it runs on my lochal server. But when I deploy to server, I have this error.

Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'Dos.Service.Web.WS.DosMainWebService'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="DosMainWebService.asmx.cs" Class="Dos.Service.Web.WS.DosMainWebService" %>

Source File: /ws/WS/DosMainWebService.asmx    Line: 1

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

Comment: Have you copied all the files? Looks to me like you are missing the .cs

Comment: Does the `DosMainWebService.asmx.cs` code behind file exist in the correct location on the server?  Does it define a class called `DosMainWebService`, and is that class defined ion the `Dos.Service.Web.WS` namespace?

Comment: @Chris, I checked but .cs file is in server.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error...

I solved it by changing the properties of my `Xzy.asmx` file:

- Set `Build Action` to `Content`
- Set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer` (in my case it was set to "Do not copy")

I hope this helps anyone...

Comment: Set Copy to Output Directory to Copy if newer (in my case it was set to "Do not copy")

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you deploy the WebService bin folder to the server. I believe it is missing your webservice dlls.

Comment: I checked my bin folder and it is deployed to server.

Comment: Might be some assembly missing. Use FusionLog to identify the missing ones. Please use this link on using FusionLog

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net

Answer (score 1):

I think you first of all check namespace asmx.cs same asmx

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have one solution file with webservice and other class libraries and the webservice app consumes the dll from these class libraries. I can see one problem is probably you're using project type as website for webservice which creates problem while resolving type issue for webservice namespace. so the solution would be create a new solution as web application project type and then add the project libraries and it should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

after testing many suggested solutions on the web
all the issue was:

every time I was publishing only web service.asmx file

but after republish all the solution it works..because webservice.asmx has its own dll files